# Структура laravel на примере интернет-магазина

Tags: php, laravel

Изучаю Laravel. Хочется понять структуру валидации данных.

Делаю интернет-магазин. Есть корзина, в которой содержатся товары, есть поля для личных данных и есть поле промокод. Пользователь, отправляя свои данные, отправляет их в POST запросе, т.е. есть поля `$request->promocode, $request->phone` и т.д.. Правильно ли я понимаю, что делать всю валидацию и большое ветвление по проверке промокода и т.д. в контроллере - моветон? Если да, то каким образом сделать это все правильно?

Данный вопрос является довольно абстрактным, но, на мой взгляд, несет в себе большую помощь тем, кто только понял весь паттерн MVC и начинает вникать в web-разработку еще глубже.

Comment: При чём тут Laravel я не совсем понял.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan хочу понять именно структуру laravel - как правильно использовать события, контракты и т.д., практики не могу нигде толковой найти по ларе. В теории - все понятно, все супер, а как это на практике применять - не совсем понимаю.

Comment: В документации же они показывают примеры как используются события те же, контракты тут больше ООП в общем, а не сам ларавел, не забывайте что это фреймворк, он дает вам инструменты, а вы уже их используете как вам нужно, минимальные примеры есть в документации.